# C++ array interval

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

See my full code below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstring>


double MAX(int Size,double arr[]){
int max =arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < Size; ++i)
{
    if(fabsf(arr[i])>max) 
    max = fabsf(arr[i]);
}
return max;
        
}

double SUM(int Size,double arr[]){
double sum = 0;
int i = Size -Size;

do{
    i++;
    if(arr[i]>0) break;
}while(i>0);

if(i==0) return 0;

for(i=i;i<Size;i++)
    sum =sum+arr[i];    
return sum;
}






void sort(int Size,double *arr, double A, double B){
int count = 0;
int i,j;
for(i = 0;i<Size;i++){
    double tmp = *(arr+i)<0?  : *(arr+i);
    if(A<=tmp && tmp<=B){
        count ++;
    }
}

i = 0;
while(count>0){
    printf("%d",count);
    double tmp = *(arr+i)<0? : *(arr+i);
    if(A<=tmp && tmp<=B){
        for(j =i;j<Size;j++){
            *(arr+j)=*(arr+j+1);
        }
        *(arr+Size-1)=0;
        count--;
        Size--;
    }
    if(A>tmp || tmp>B){
        i++;
    }   
  }
}






int main(int argc, char** argv) {
double *arr;
int arrSize = 10;
int ifRand = 0;
double A,B,max,sum;

char test[] = "-rand";
for(int i=1;i<argc;i++)
{
    if(strcmp(test,argv[i])==0){
        ifRand = 1;
        break;
    }
}

fflush(stdin);
if(ifRand){
    srand(time(0));
    arr = new double[arrSize];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        arr[i] =(double)rand()/RAND_MAX*100-50;
    A = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*100-50;
    B = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*100-50;
    if(A>B){
        double tmp = A;
        A=B;
        B=tmp;
    }
}else{
    printf("\n Ievadiet masiva garumu: ");
    scanf("%d", &arrSize);
    arr = new double[arrSize];
    double elements;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        printf("Ievadiet masiva elementu %d \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &elements);
        arr[i] = elements;
    }
    printf("Ievadiet A \n");
    scanf("%lf", &A);
    printf("Ievadiet B \n");
    scanf("%lf", &B);
}
printf("Masivs:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
    printf("\%.3f  ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\nA = %.3f",A);
printf("\nB = %.3f",B);

max = MAX(arrSize,arr);
sum = SUM(arrSize,arr);
sort(arrSize,arr,A,B);

printf("\nLielaka vertiba ir %.3f",max);
printf("\nSumma vertibam pec pirma pozitiva elementa ir %.3f",sum);
printf("\nMasivs pec saspiesanas:");
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
    printf("\%.3f  ", arr[i]);
}

return ifRand;
}
```

I have an array where the user decides the size and the element values, he has also to decide the interval A and B. All the numbers between A and B has to move in front of array, the code I have is something I found which was used for similar code, all the numbers between A and B were to be deleted and the rest of pushed to beginning.

What I need is something like: in a array of 5 elements {1,2,3,4,5} and interval A(2) and B(4). Result should look like {2,3,4,1,5}.

I don't need the code above if there is other ways. It's just what I have found and tried to use.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: could you post more complete code? Where is your main and your input? Where is `arr` coming from?

Comment: how to push elements in the interval to the front of array

Comment: As a member for a year with multiple questions, you should have had time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ErickVazovsky in C++, arrays are contiguous blocks of memory. If you want to put something at the beginning of an array, you can't just "push" it there. You have to move everything else over yourself to make space for it, then put it there yourself. If you wan't to be able to simply "push" things, you should use a `std::vector`

Comment: This code still won't compile, even after the edit. What are `MAX` and `SUM`?

Comment: added full code

Comment: @ErickVazovsky -- You should not have uppercase names for your functions.  And the solution is to use `stable_partition` and not have to write all of those loops.

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush). Best not to make the code unportable so readily.

Comment: @ErickVazovsky In addition to `std::stable_partition`, you have `std::accumulate` to add the range of numbers up, `std::max_element` to determine the maximum element, `std::sort` to sort the numbers, etc.  Basically practically most of your program could have been written without loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition and use it like this:

```
void sort_to_front(int Size, double *arr, double A, double B)
{
    stable_partition(arr, arr + Size, [&](double a){ return a >= A && a <= B; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is something like: in a array of 5 elements {1,2,3,4,5} and interval A(2) and B(4). Result should look like {2,3,4,1,5}.
>
> I don't need the code above if there is other ways. It's just what I have found and tried to use.

You can use standard algorithm `std::stable_partition` declared in header `<algorithm>`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::pair<int, int> range(2, 4);

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::stable_partition( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ),
        [&]( const int &item ) 
        { 
            return range.first <= item && item <= range.second; 
        });

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 1 5
```